# Estou com problemas com meu metodo de atualizar na aplicação java,não atualiza no banco

Tags: java, mysql

```
public Boolean alterar(Exemplo exemplor){
       Boolean retorno = false;
       String qry = "update funcionario set nome = ?,rg = ?,orgaoExped = ?,dataExped = ?,dataDeNascimento = ?,email = ?,estadoCivil = ?,sexo = ?,cnh = ?,titulo = ?,"
                    + "zona = ?,secao = ?,carteiraTrabalho = ?,serieCtrabalho = ?,cartResevista = ?,"
                    + "serieResevista = ?,cor = ?,pis = ?,conta_corrente = ?,agencia_banco = ?,"
                    + "nome_banco = ?,numero_banco = ? WHERE cpf = ?";
       try{
          PreparedStatement pstt = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(qry); 
            pstt.setString(1, exemplor.getNome());
            pstt.setInt(2, exemplor.getRg());
            pstt.setString(3, exemplor.getOrgaoExped());
            pstt.setDate(4, exemplor.getDataExped());
            pstt.setDate(5, exemplor.getDataDeNascimento());
            pstt.setString(6, exemplor.getEmail());
            pstt.setString(7, exemplor.getEstadoCivil());
            pstt.setString(8, exemplor.getSexo());
            pstt.setInt(9, exemplor.getCnh());
            pstt.setInt(10, exemplor.getTitulo());
            pstt.setInt(11, exemplor.getZona());
            pstt.setInt(12, exemplor.getSecao());
            pstt.setInt(13, exemplor.getCarteiraTrabalho());
            pstt.setInt(14, exemplor.getSerieCTrabalho());
            pstt.setInt(15, exemplor.getCartResevista());
            pstt.setInt(16, exemplor.getSerieResevista());
            pstt.setString(17, exemplor.getCor());
            pstt.setInt(18, exemplor.getPis());
            pstt.setString(19, exemplor.getConta_corrente());
            pstt.setString(20, exemplor.getAgencia_banco());
            pstt.setString(21, exemplor.getNome_banco());
            pstt.setInt(22, exemplor.getNumero_banco()); 
            pstt.setString(23, exemplor.getCpf());
            pstt.executeUpdate();
            pstt.close();
            retorno = true;
       }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu no erro sql...  " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return retorno;

//Aqui é o botão alterar no jframe

  Exemplo inse = new Exemplo();

                 inse.setNome(nome.getText());
                 inse.setRg(rg.getX());
                 inse.setOrgaoExped(orgaoExped.getText());
                 inse.setDataExped(dataExped);
                 inse.setDataDeNascimento(dataDeNascimento);
                 inse.setEmail(email.getText());
                 inse.setEstadoCivil((String) estadoCivil.getSelectedItem());
                 inse.setSexo((String) sexo.getSelectedItem());
                 inse.setCnh(cnh.getX());
                 inse.setTitulo(titulo.getX());
                 inse.setZona(zona.getX());
                 inse.setSecao(secao.getX());
                 inse.setCarteiraTrabalho(carteiraTrabalho.getX());
                 inse.setSerieCTrabalho(serieCTrabalho.getX());
                 inse.setCartResevista(cartResevista.getX());
                 inse.setSerieResevista(serieResevista.getX());
                 inse.setCor((String) cor.getSelectedItem());
                 inse.setPis(pis.getX());
                 inse.setConta_corrente(conta_corrente.getText());
                 inse.setAgencia_banco(agencia_banco.getText());
                 inse.setNome_banco(nome_banco.getText());
                 inse.setNumero_banco(numero_banco.getX());
                 inse.setCpf(cpf.getText());

                 new ExemploDAO().alterar(inse);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Funcionario atualizado com sucesso...");
```

Comment: já checou se `exemplor` está realmente sendo preenchido? Depure o código e coloque um breakpoint na assinatura do metodo e veja se este objeto não está chegando vazio.

Comment: Opa. Blza? tenta fazer um Conexao.commit(); depois de pstt.executeUpdate();